# Context Menu Strip Control With and Without Selected Grid

Tags: vb.net, listview, contextmenustrip

I really don't know what to search so I'll just ask this:

I have a context menu strip linked to a listview,

what I need is that when I right click to a highlighted variable in the grid list view, the menu for items will be displayed, and
when I right click to an empty grid, the grid settings will be displayed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: sounds like there are *two* context menus involved, but please explain what a `highlighted variable in the grid list view` is or means

Comment: I mean selected Item, when I select and item in the list view and press right click it should display things like copy paste stuffs related to the item, and when there are no highlighted item the context menu should show menus for listview like, columns, rows..

Comment: In mouse down: `If myLV.SelectedItems.Count > 0 then ...display item menu Else ...display system menu End If`.  Note that the question changed in the comment...also the LV doesnt care which mouse button is pressed to select an item and making users deselect items to get at a different menu is cruel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt the user will appreciate your approach; you plan to display 2 different menus from the same action - a click.  It may not be apparent how to get one menu or the other.  Further, it is not clear why the "Settings" or main menu would ever need to be hidden from them.

Rather than 2 menus, why not 1 menu with 2 submenus, to make it easy to find them?

```
Private Sub myLV_MouseUp(sender...
    If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) Then

        lvCMS.Items("ItemMenu").Enabled = (myLV.SelectedItems.Count > 0)

        ' show (may need if there ARE 2 menus)
        lvCMS.Show(myLV.PointToScreen(New Point(e.X, e.Y)))

    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

The LV will show an assigned menu on its own, but if you have 2, you may want/need to display it manually, which is shown.  By using the `MouseUp` event the LV has already reacted to `MouseDn` and changed the selected item.  The only thing that varies menu-wise is whether the `ItemMenu` is enabled or not.

Clicking on an empty area deselects an item.  Barring a button to do the same, it is hard to deselect an item because the empty area can get be almost nonexistent:

[image]

Only the orange-ish area is empty grid, add one more item to fill in the bottom and cause a scroll bar and there is none.  This is partly why a separate menu and special set of conditions may not be a good idea.